# Photos "Saved from ..." on iOS using swift

Tags: ios, swift, metadata, photo

Is there any way how to find out what app saved/shared an image to apple's Photos app on iOS using preferably swift?
I am not able to see any useful metadata either in CIimage or PHAsset.

Currently trying something like this with now luck:

```
func metadata() {
    let options = PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions()

    requestContentEditingInput(with: options) { input, _ in
        guard let url = input?.fullSizeImageURL,
            let image = CIImage(contentsOf: url) else { return }
        let properties = image.properties
        print("\(properties)")
    }
}
```

Any idea where it could be stored?
See image for what I need to access.

[image]